# How to decorate a dependency twice with StructureMap

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, decorator, structuremap

I have a dependency configured in StructureMap and would like to decorate it twice. I have used the `EnrichWith` method like below but only the second decorator gets executed (`ResultistAdvertisementInjector`). If I switch them only the other decorator gets executed.

```
For<IResultListViewModelMapper<ZoekObject>>().Use<ResultListViewModelMapper<ZoekObject>>()
    .EnrichWith(original => new ResultListDateSeparatorInjector<ZoekObject>(original))
    .EnrichWith(original => new ResultistAdvertisementInjector<ZoekObject>(original));
```

How can I enrich a dependency with two decorators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just nest the 'decorating' classes yourself, for example like:

```
For<IResultListViewModelMapper<ZoekObject>>().Use<ResultListViewModelMapper<ZoekObject>>()
                .EnrichWith(original => 
                new ResultListDateSeparatorInjector<ZoekObject>(
                    new ResultistAdvertisementInjector<ZoekObject>(original)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I think you can do something like this:

```
For<IResultListViewModelMapper<ZoekObject>>()
    .Use<ResultListViewModelMapper<ZoekObject>>()
    .EnrichWith(original =>
        new ResultListDateSeparatorInjector<ZoekObject>(
            new ResultistAdvertisementInjector<ZoekObject>(original)));
```